# Assign 3D data value based on a 2D index profile

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D numpy array:

```
data0 = np.random.rand(30, 50, 50)
```

I have a 2D surface:

```
surf = np.random.rand(50, 50) * 30
surf = surf.astype(int)
```

Now I want to assign '0' to data0 along the surface profile. Which I know for loop can achieve this:

```
for xx in range(50):
    for yy in range(50):
        data0[0:surf[xx, yy], xx, yy] = 0
```

Data0 is a 3D volume with size of 30 * 50 * 50. surf is a 2D surface profile with size of 50 * 50. What I am trying to do is filling '0' from top to the surface (axis=0) in the volume

Here, 'for' loop is very slow, and it is inefficient when data0 is very huge. Could someone advise how to efficiently assign the values based on the surf profile?

Comment: `data0[0:surf, xx, yy] = 0` - what kind of indexing would that be given that `surf` has the dimensions (50, 50)? Have you tried running this example? It remains unclear what the desired output should be.

Comment: Sorry, the for loop should be:        data0[0:surf[xx, yy], xx, yy] = 0. Please see the edited question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `numpy`, you can create a mask with `z`-index values below your `surf` values set to `True`, then fill those cells with zeros:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
x, y, z = 4, 5, 3
data0 = np.random.rand(z, x, y)

surf = np.random.rand(x, y) * z
surf = surf.astype(int)

#your attempt
#we copy the data just for the comparison
data_loop = data0.copy()
for xx in range(x):
    for yy in range(y):
        data_loop[0:surf[xx, yy], xx, yy] = 0

#again, we copy the data just for the comparison
data_np = data0.copy()
#masking the cells according to your index comparison criteria
mask = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(data0.shape[0])[:,None, None], data0.shape) < surf[None, :]
#set masked values to zero
data_np[mask] = 0

#check for equivalence of resulting arrays
print((data_np==data_loop).all())
```

I am sure there is a better, numpier way to generate the index number mask. As it is, this version is not necessarily faster. This depends on the shape of your array.
For `x=500`, `y=200`, and `z=3000`, your loop takes 1.42 s and my numpy approach 1.94 s.
For the same array size but with shape `x=5000`, `y=2000`, and `z=30`, your loop approach takes 7.06 s and the numpy approach 1.95 s.

Comment: Awesome. This works and pretty fast. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good luck with your project.